# changing android package name

Tags: android, package, manifest

I want to change the package name for an app which is not yet published in the Market. Is there a way to use the new package name as the uniqueId on Market/Play and while still using the old package name in my code?

Comment: `R` is always generated in the package that is defined in `package="your.package.here"` in the manifest. Your java files can use a different package though. You may need to fix the import of `R` manually if you change the manifest.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the package name in the manifest will change how Google Play reads your package name.  You don't need to change the package name anywhere else to accomplish that.  In Eclipse, the package name for classes can be changed independently (directly under src).

As zapl mentions, you may need to handle a few manual items if your application package name differs from that of the classes within (shortcuts that assume everything is in the same package don't always work in that case).  For example, using ".classname" may need to change to a fully qualified classname in the manifest and elsewhere.

If you're looking for a way to change the package name to be different in Google Play than it is in the manifest, then no you can't (it wouldn't be a good idea anyway).  You can, however, use library projects to create a new app with the new package name without changing the original code or manifest.  Minimal code/xml would need to be written.